# Changing Rails Default Date Parse Option Hide options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know how to change the default option for the Date.parse 
(which ActiveRecord is using on all date fields).  I would like the 
"comp" option to default to true so I don't have to account for 2- 
digit dates throughout my application.

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#M001228

Answer (score 1):

You could overload/monkey-patch the existing method. eg:

```
class Date
  class << self
   alias :parse_with_comp :parse
  end
  def self.parse(str='-4712-01-01', sg=ITALY)
    self.parse_with_comp(str,true,sg) 
  end
end
```